# Windows work flow activity designer not validating invisible items

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

I have created on "WorkflowDesigner"in C#/WPF code, I have populated with some activities which are not seen in GUI with out scrolling.

If there is any error in the data bounded it show display some error icon in top. 
Now the validation error only happening while  i am scrolling the items.

is there any way for force update validation for entire activities in workflow editor (including the hidden item due to scroll) . Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used to run away from visualization, We zoomed to fit to window and then reset to previous zoom level.